# The image of a smooth idempotent function as smooth surface (manifold)

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $f \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth function, and it satisfies that $f \circ f = f$.

How to prove that $S := f(\mathbb R^n)$ *is a smooth surface?*

Here the definition of a surface is that each point $x$ in $S$ has a neighbourhood $U$ in $S$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$, and a smooth surface is the case when the isomorphism from $\mathbb R^k$ to $U$ is also smooth (of class $C^{(m)}$, $m > 0$).

Examples like identity and linear projections indicates that the rank of the Jacobian $f'$ defines the dimension of the surface.
In fact, the derivative (Jacobian) of $f$ must satisfies:
$$
 f' f' = f',
$$
and therefore becomes a projection from $T_x\mathbb R^n$ to $T_{f(x)} S$.

Let $g(x) := f(x) - x$, we can see that $g(x) = 0 \leftrightarrow x \in S$.
But how to prove that $g$ has a rank $n - k$ at every point in $S$?
I don't see the constance of rank.

The question comes from Zorich *Mathematics Analysis* Chapter 12, §1, and my notations follows the book.

Comment: See the Theorem $1.15$ of this [link](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Topics_in_Differential_Geometry/zNkOCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=theorem+1.15+of+peter+w.+michor+topics+in+differential+geometry&pg=PA12&printsec=frontcover). Here is an online version of the same [book](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf)

Comment: @Atnamus Thank you! I didn't expect to find an identical theorem in a text of differential geometry.